# Can I discard a spell not drawn by Magick Shoppe?

Tags: eldritch-horror, eldritch-horror-under-the-pyramids

> When you gain this card, immediately gain 2 Spells. Then discard 1 Spell and this card.

This wording implies that I can keep both Spells and discard a previously owned Spell, but it kind of breaks the idea of going shopping for spells and picking from a wide selection. Ruling?

Comment: You have enough "resources" to buy a spell, but you _really_ want both. Luckily you're in a Magick Shoppe, where they'll make a deal for your other Magickes!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text is unambiguous.
Have in mind it's not worded "Then discard 1 of these Spells and this card." while it could be.
There is no relevant ruling, as this is not a rules issue.

Comment: To your point, I noticed another card "Book of Spells" that says "gain 2 Spells and discard 1 of them" so even if this were an oversight, the existence of a case where they clarify the point makes it even less likely of it being an oversight.